# Unique list based on two cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to extract a list of unique customers, I would like to extract a list based on a combination of two columns, column F and column K. Is there a way to update this code, that would be effective?

[image]

```
Sub FilterUniqueCustomer()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Advance Filter
  Range("F1").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Range("F1:F100").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
    "S1"), Unique:=True
  ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6

  'Copy Values      
  Range("T2:T100").Select
  Selection.copy
  Range("U2").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

  'Clear Formatting      
  Range("N4").Select
  Selection.copy
  Columns("S:S").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears clipboard

  Call DeleteZerosCustomer
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this using a dictionary to get unique combinations and array to work faster than in sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim arr(), i As Long, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")                    '<==Change as required
        arr = .Range("F1:K6").Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            dict(arr(i, 1) & "," & arr(i, 6)) = 1
        Next
    End With

    Dim key As Variant, rowCounter As Long
    For Each key In dict.keys
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Split(key, ",")  '<== Change output sheet as required
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get a result in Sheet3. Do I need to set anything up for  CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")? No value seems to be inputted into arr. I also noticed arr is set to a Range("F1:K6"), there is data in columns G:J, is that going to affect the uniqueness of the result?

Comment: you need to set the range to where your data is. You said you want columns F and K no? That becomes column 1 and 6 of the array read from F:K.

Comment: The complete range is A1:N100. Company is in column F and Job is in col K. I want to extract the records that are unique combination of col F and col K.

Comment: But if there are repeats which do you keep?

Comment: I was going to work on these, but ideally col L has a number in it, col M is empty and if these are satisfied select the record with the oldest date in col H.